Looking for examples of 2 or more data sets to test reproducibility
I'm working to test reproducibility given two or more data sets. For example, the Boston Housing can easily be split into two groups, such as:
Boston1 <- MASS::Boston[1:300, ]
Boston2 <- MASS::Boston[301:505, ]

It's possible to build models on each of those data sets to test reproducibility, such as:
lm1 <- lm(medv ~ ., data = Boston1)
lm2 <- lm(meds ~ ., data = Boston2)

From there it's easy to test if the models produce similar results for both data sets.
But are there any actual data sets which are totally independent of one another? For example, one researcher may have been at Michigan and the other at Kentucky, running the same experiment? Obviously they would have different subjects, but that's the point to test if the results reproduce accurately on truly independent data!
Where are any such data sets found to actually test reproducibility?
